# Set the response message content but I can't retrieve it

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http, asp.net-web-api

I've got a server method that takes and codifies a list of strings, since IE9 doesn't read json format, what I want is to set the string in the content of an http response message. I seems to do it well but when I get the response I can's find the response on the body, what I can see is only the length of what I set in the response message.

here is the code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage m = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        List<string> returnlist = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
                   //string treatment        
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        response.Content = new StringContent(string.Join(",", returnlist));
        return response;
    }
```

this is what the string contains "file1,file2,file3"
but I can't find it debugging in visual studio or firebug

The response that I get is:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:

{
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
}
```

How can I set and then get the response message?

In case of need the js here is it:

```
self.uploadfiles = function () {
        //startSpinner();

        if (!self.isOldIE()) {
            var loc = window.location;
            base_url = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host;
            baseUrl = base_url + "/";

            var save = true;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', baseUrl + 'Home/Upload');
            xhr.send(formdata);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
                //The responseText is the same as above
                if (xhr.responseText.length > 0) {  

                   //do stuff
      }
    };
```

Comment: The status says it all... error 404 : you're requesting a page that doesn't exist... the code you show here above is probably never hit...

Comment: That's becouse I was handling the response in the js ajax like a json, I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the response using Javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', baseUrl + 'Home/Upload', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)  { 
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        // do something about the error
    }
};
xhr.send(formdata);
```

**Note** the third boolean parameter of the open() method for getting asynchronously.

Comment: I assumed you were working within an ApiController, but sounds like that may not be the case.  Keep your original code and try the new answer to get the response.

Comment: I'm using Controller class, but what I need is to create a response (not in json to use in ie9), and the retrieve it from the client using js. The client side is resolved, but I don't see in the response the string in the http message that I send.

Comment: Can you also paste your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Join(",", returnlist));
        return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the browsers doesn't show the entire body of the http response. So my solution was to write the header of the response and get the header from js.
Maybe somebody knows why the browsers doesn't show the body, or has a better solution.

This is my controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage m = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        List<string> returnlist = new List<string>();


        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; //Uploaded file
            //Use the following properties to get file's name, size and MIMEType
            int fileSize = file.ContentLength;

            if (file.FileName != "")
            {
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), file.FileName.ToString().Split('.')[1].ToString());
                returnlist.Add(fileName);

            }

        }


//Here I write the response message headers
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        response.Content = new StringContent(string.Join(",", returnlist), Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

        response.Headers.Add("data", string.Join(",", returnlist));

        return response;
    }
```

And here is how I get the header response:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', baseUrl + 'Home/Upload');
            xhr.send(formdata);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
                if (xhr.responseText.length > 0) {
//header response
                    var response = xhr.responseText;
                 }
```